# use stored procedure parameter modify cursor select statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure that creates a table based on several others.  I have a parameter to the stored procedure called "filterDown" that will be an ID.  If filterDown is =0 then I want to include all IDs.  If filterDown is anything else, I only want to select that ID.

Here is my cursor declaration in my code:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE country ( 
      fromDate IN DATE,
      toDate IN DATE,
      filterDown IN INT,
      chunkSize IN INT
      ) AS 

    --cursor
    cursor cc is
      select c.id, cd.population_total_count, cd.evaluation_date, cf.gdp_total_dollars
      from countries c
      join country_demographics cd on c.id = cd.country_id
      join country_financials cf on cd.country_id = cf.country_id and cf.evaluation_date = cd.evaluation_date
      where cd.evaluation_date > fromDate and cd.evaluation_date < toDate
      order by c.id,cd.evaluation_date;

--lots more code down here.....
```

In other words, the stored procedure should be able to filter down with this parameter based on the country id, with a default value indicating that all countries should be included.  Countries not meeting the criteria should not be in the derived table when the procedure is complete.

How would I specify in my cursor to do something like that?

EDIT:
Here's how I'm calling the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure testing as
  UPPER1 DATE;
  LOWER1 DATE;
  FILTERON1 NUMBER;
  CHUNKSIZE1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  UPPER1 := TO_DATE('2000/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd');
  LOWER1 := TO_DATE('2005/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd');
  FILTERON1 := 143;
  CHUNKSIZE1 := 250;

  country(UPPER1,LOWER1,FILTERON1,CHUNKSIZE1);

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to add something like this to your `WHERE` clause

```
...
where cd.evaluation_date > fromDate 
  and cd.evaluation_date < toDate
  and (filterDown = 0 or c.id = filterDown)
...
```

Comment: doesn't appear to be working.  when I supply filterDown=150 it grabs ID 1 for some reason?  then when filterDown=0, how does it know to get all IDs? (essentially ignore the filterdown variable)

Comment: @Ted - That seems unlikely.  Are you certain that the parenthesis in your query are correct?  Are you certain that the `filterDown` parameter has the value you think it does?

Comment: I realized that I have a 1 in there now.  very careless of me. :(